# How to find the end of content on the last page of pdf and insert a text block after it?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Now we create a separate page using the addPage PDDocument method and add a block of text to it.

However, I need a way to add a block of text to the last page immediately after the content. Or, if the block does not fit, then create it on a new page.

As I understand it, first we need to find the end of the content. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Essentially you simply have to determine the bounding box of the existing page content. You can find a simple page bounding box finder in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52969119/1729265).