# PDFBox: how to determine bounding box of vector figure (path shape)

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have simple PDF generated by Apache FOP + jEuclid. This PDF has vector graphics for math formulas and the text:

[image]

Link to PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4ksnud78bu9oz5/test.pdf?dl=0

I would like to know bounding box (x,y,width,height) for each vector graphics. I've tried this example: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.24/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java, but it doesn't output any information , only this:

```
Processing page: 1
```

In the Acrobat I can select the vector images in the Tags tree and it highlights them:
[image]

My question - how to determine bounding box for vector images via PDFBox API?

Comment: Maybe you can modify this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931422/pdfbox-2-0-2-calling-of-pagedrawer-processpage-method-caught-exceptions

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the advice. I've tried it, but looks like PDFGraphicsStreamEngine is very low-level feature for my purpose. It allows to determine coordinates for each glyph in the formulas, i.e. it catches paths for each concrete glyph. I can't understand when one one group of paths end and start of another group...

Comment: You can catch "fillPath", that would help for this PDF.

Comment: fillPath called 13 times, i.e. for each glyph/character in both formulas. Actually, besides bounding box I need to know alternate (or actual) text related to formula. So may be I have to use PDFMarkedContentExtractor.

Comment: Your PDF does not have alternate text for these vector graphics. You can have a look at it with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Hmm, it's very strange. I've checked PDF Acrobat (full version, not Reader) in Tags tab and it has alternate and actual texts. Also you can find the text '/Alt (Math)' and '/ActualText (<math xmlns=' if open PDF in any text editor just a text file (in Windows, for example, Notepad, Notepad++).

Comment: Oops, you're right, I searched in the content stream (which can also have this). What you found is at `Root/StructTreeRoot/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/ActualText` and `Root/StructTreeRoot/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[2]/K/[0]/ActualText`. That's the structure tree, which I'm mostly clueless about :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the figures in question are appropriately tagged (as they are in your example document), you can determine their bounding boxes based on the PDFBox `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine`.

You actually can make use of the [`BoundingBoxFinder`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/BoundingBoxFinder.java#L43) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52969119/1729265) (based on the `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine`) which determines the bounding box of all content of a page, you merely have to retrieve the bounding box information marked content sequence by marked content sequence.

The following class does that by storing bounding box information in a hierarchy of `MarkedContext` objects

```java
public class MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder extends BoundingBoxFinder {
    public MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder(PDPage page) {
        super(page);
        contents.add(content);
    }

    @Override
    public void processPage(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        super.processPage(page);
        endMarkedContentSequence();
    }

    @Override
    public void beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName tag, COSDictionary properties) {
        MarkedContent current = contents.getLast();
        if (rectangle != null) {
            if (current.boundingBox != null)
                add(current.boundingBox);
            current.boundingBox = rectangle;
        }
        rectangle = null;
        MarkedContent newContent = new MarkedContent(tag, properties);
        contents.addLast(newContent);
        current.children.add(newContent);

        super.beginMarkedContentSequence(tag, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void endMarkedContentSequence() {
        MarkedContent current = contents.removeLast();
        if (rectangle != null) {
            if (current.boundingBox != null)
                add(current.boundingBox);
            current.boundingBox = (Rectangle2D) rectangle.clone();
        } else if (current.boundingBox != null)
            rectangle = (Rectangle2D) current.boundingBox.clone();

        super.endMarkedContentSequence();
    }

    public static class MarkedContent {
        public MarkedContent(COSName tag, COSDictionary properties) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.properties = properties;
        }

        public final COSName tag;
        public final COSDictionary properties;
        public final List<MarkedContent> children = new ArrayList<>();
        public Rectangle2D boundingBox = null;
    }

    public final MarkedContent content = new MarkedContent(COSName.DOCUMENT, null);
    public final Deque<MarkedContent> contents = new ArrayDeque<>();
}
```

*([MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder.java#L31) utility class)*

You can apply it to a `PDPage pdPage` like this

```java
MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder boxFinder = new MarkedContentBoundingBoxFinder(pdPage);
boxFinder.processPage(pdPage);
MarkedContent markedContent = boxFinder.content;
```

*(excerpt from [DetermineBoundingBox](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/DetermineBoundingBox.java#L174) helper method `drawMarkedContentBoundingBoxes`)*

You can output the bounding boxes from that `markedContent` object like this:

```java
void printMarkedContentBoundingBoxes(MarkedContent markedContent, String prefix) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(prefix).append(markedContent.tag.getName());
    builder.append(' ').append(markedContent.boundingBox);
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
    for (MarkedContent child : markedContent.children)
        printMarkedContentBoundingBoxes(child, prefix + "  ");
}
```

*([DetermineBoundingBox](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/DetermineBoundingBox.java#L198) helper method)*

In case of your example document you get

```
Document java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=90.35800170898438,y=758.10498046875,w=128.63946533203125,h=10.2509765625]
  Figure java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=90.35800170898438,y=758.10498046875,w=44.6771240234375,h=10.2509765625]
  P java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=136.79600524902344,y=760.1184081963065,w=43.137100359018405,h=6.383056943803922]
  Figure java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=184.2926788330078,y=758.10498046875,w=34.70478820800781,h=10.2509765625]
```

Similarly you can draw the bounding boxes on the PDF using the `drawMarkedContentBoundingBoxes` methods of [DetermineBoundingBox](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/DetermineBoundingBox.java#L173). In case of your example document you get:

[image: screen shot]